# VBA Access replaced checkbox with image

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to make some records on the checkbox are replaced with the image. But in this case, all record become replaced. Somebody help me please? I have the following code:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT tbl_export_def.nutTar AS isExport, 
tbl_export_def.fieldName, tbl_export_def.fieldAlias, 
tbl_export_def.Description, tbl_export_def.Unitmeasurement, 
tbl_export_def.SortID, tbl_export_def.isKey, tbl_export_def.key, 
tbl_export_def.table FROM tbl_export_def ORDER BY tbl_export_def.SortID ;"

Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.ExportData.ControlSource = "nutTar"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Q_isExport").SQL = strSQL  ' change string Query
Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.ExportData.ControlSource = "isExport"
If DLookup("isKey", "Q_isExport", "isKey = True and table = 'tbl_scenarios'") 
Then
    Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.Image_Key.Visible = True
Else
    Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.Image_Key.Visible = False
End If
Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Q_isExport where 
(Q_isExport.isExport=true)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Dim isKey As Boolean
' ...  
isKey = DLookup("isKey", "Q_isExport", "table = 'tbl_scenarios'")
Form_frm_exportRaw_fields.Image_Key.Visible = isKey
' ...
```

Comment: So this is a continous form? Then Visible is for the control, not by the record. You'll have to use a bound image if you wish individual settings for each record.